# Showing derived relations

Tags: alloy

Consider a simple graphical structure `G` that defines a couple of relations (`r1` and `r2`) over a set `X` of nodes. I want to talk about whether my graphs have a certain property called `wf_G`. This property is defined by deriving a further relation `r3` from `r1` and `r2`, and then constraining `r3`.

```
sig X {}

sig G { r1, r2 : X -> X }

pred wf_G [g : G] {
  let r3 = (g.r1 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden) |
  one r3
}

run wf_G for 1 G, 2 X
```

(I should say: this is very much a toy example.)

The thing is, `r3` is not shown in the Visualizer, because it is a `let`-defined relation. I would like it to be shown in the Visualizer because otherwise I would have to derive it manually in my head. Is there a way to (for instance) annotate the `let` statement to instruct the Visualizer to include the derived relation, e.g. like the following?

```
let {show} r3 = (g.r1 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden) |
```

---

My current workaround is to include `r3` in the signature of `G`, and then constrain `r3` according to its definition in terms of `r1` and `r2`. That is, I have been writing:

```
sig X {}

sig G { r1, r2, r3 : X -> X }

pred wf_G [g : G] {
  (g.r3) = (g.r1 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden) 
  && 
  one (g.r3)
}

run wf_G for 1 G, 2 X
```

This is less appealing than my original code because

- it conflates the primitive relations `r1` and `r2` with the derived relation `r3`, and
- it feels less computationally efficient to allow `r3` to be initially any relation, and then to constrain it to be a particular relation (though I haven't run timing tests to check whether this is the case).

---

**Edit.** Daniel has suggested encoding `r3` as a 0-ary function. I don't see how this can be done, but I can see how a 1-ary function would work:

```
sig X {}

sig G { r1, r2 : X -> X }

fun r3 [g : G] : X -> X {
  (g.r1 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden) . (g.r2 - iden)
}

pred wf_G [g : G] {
  one r3[g]
}

run wf_G for 1 G, 2 X
```

If `r3` is encoded as a function like this, is it possible to show it in the visualiser? That would certainly solve my problem very satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a function of no arguments, it will be treated as a skolem constant and will be available in the visualizer as a relation to be displayed under the standard customizations. Might that work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. I don't see how a 0-ary function would work here, but a 1-ary function would work. Please see my edited question above.